# Problems of reading Excel 2003 using Oledb

Tags: .net, excel, oledb

I tried to use Oledb to open Excel 2003.  Looks like I can read most of data, but for some cells (such as number), the value returned is Null.  Any suggestion?

My connection string:
ConnectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add ";IMEX=1" to the connection string. That tells the driver to read "intermixed" (numbers, dates, strings etc) data columns as text.